# camel elasticsearch access port 80

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, elasticsearch-plugin

I have port 9200 proxied via 80 on my server running elasticsearch. I have a camel route that needs to index documents to this server.

Is it supported in the camel-elasticsearch plugin? ie access elastic search via a non 9300 port?

I understand that port 9300 uses a native elasticsearch transport protocol.

What are my options here? Can I proxy 9300 via apache? I'm not sure if that works.

Or does the camel-elasticsearch plugin support http transport? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The port you are referring to, it *is* the [HTTP port](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html):

> **`http.port`**    A bind port range. Defaults to `9200-9300`.
>
> **`http.publish_port`**    The port that HTTP clients should use when communicating with this node. Useful when a cluster node is behind a
>   proxy or firewall and the http.port is not directly addressable from
>   the outside. Defaults to the actual port assigned via http.port.
>
> **`http.bind_host`**   The host address to bind the HTTP service to. Defaults to `http.host` (if set) or `network.bind_host`.
>
> **`http.publish_host`**    The host address to publish for HTTP clients to connect to. Defaults to `http.host` (if set) or
>   `network.publish_host`.
>
> **`http.host`**    Used to set the `http.bind_host` and the `http.publish_host` Defaults to `http.host` or `network.host`.

So you really don't need a proxy, you can have elasticsearch listen directly on port 80.

If you already have a process running on port 80; then you can proxy the connections to 9200 (and leave elastic search as default).

---

> Java Transport Client ---> Apache HTTP Proxy(80) ----> ES (9300) [ Can
>   I do this? As I understand that Java Transport Client uses a non-http
>   protocol? ]

The protocol has nothing to do with the port.

Simply pass `80` to `InetSocketTransportAddress`. See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) for a complete example.

Comment: I understand that 9200 is elasticsearch's http port and this can be proxied via port 80. But my question was if I were to use the Elasticsearch Java API (that uses the transport client though port 9300) outside the firewall, what are my options?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here.  If you are concerned that port 9300 may be blocked from your _client_, then configure your client to query on port 80; is this what you are trying to do and are stuck?

Comment: `Java Transport Client ---> Apache HTTP Proxy(80) ----> ES (9300) [ Can I do this? As I understand that Java Transport Client uses a non-http protocol? ] `